# In Terminal "echo", how do I get to Brace expressions to match?

Tags: linux, terminal, echo

playing with echo(Im rather new to Linux or Unix like Os) in Ubuntu.
This is what I want to get as output of echo 
`class=1,id=1
class=2,id=2 
and so on till...
class=100,id=100` 
So I did : `echo class={1..100},id={1..100}`
I understand that I have to use `{1..100}` but the trouble is I get  `class=1,id=1`(which is ok) then `class=1,id=2`(which i understand why it happens but i want the class to be equal to id)
So can anyone say how to get that output? (See lines 3 to 6)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do
    echo "class=$i, id=$i";
done
```

This loops through every number from 1 to 100 and print accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the two braces are expanded separately.

Not with echo only. You should use a variable assignment:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do echo class=$i,id=$i ; done
```

Works with Dash under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This script will probably do the trick for you,

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do
 echo class=$i,id=$i
done
```